# How to make Mapnik render Erdas images in RGB instead of grayscale?

Tags: mapnik, erdas-imagine

I have some orthophoto files (Erdas Imagine format) enclosed in a vrt file. When I view it in any desktop GIS it has proper RGB colors, but when I use the vrt in Mapnik to render some tiles, I get grayscale images as a result. Why?

Update: If I convert the Erdas Imagine files into png-s (I need transparency where there is no data) Mapnik render works ok, so I guess it's something to do with how Mapnik interprets Erdas files and its bands.

Comment: Try filing a bug report at https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues

Comment: I think i ll dig a little further, because i dont think its a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to double-check that your VRT is specifying proper red/green/blue assignments for the bands. (And possibly alpha if you have a special alpha band.)

I had a somewhat similar problem where I'd made a VRT, and Mapnik didn't seem to render anything from it. When I looked at the VRT, all four bands looked like this:

```
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
  <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
</VRTRasterBand>
...
...
```

To fix it, I manually applied proper ColorInterp assignments. I actually opened my VRT in QGIS to see how it was applying the RGB assignments. Sure enough, 1 2 and 3 corresponded directly to R G and B. So I suspect the other software must use this assumption when band assignments aren't stated?

```
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
  <ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
</VRTRasterBand>
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="2" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
  <ColorInterp>Green</ColorInterp>
</VRTRasterBand>
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="3" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
  <ColorInterp>Blue</ColorInterp>
</VRTRasterBand>
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="4" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
  <ColorInterp>Alpha</ColorInterp>
</VRTRasterBand>
```

Unfortunately, I don't remember exactly how I *created* my VRT, which resulted in all four bands being assigned to Gray (or maybe it was Unknown, [there's a complete list of values here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html)).